# C#.Net X64 Application crash when using 64bit dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, 64-bit

I have a problem running a C# application(WPF, .Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2010) targeted to x64 and uses 64bit dll (3rd party).

The problem appear when I run the 64bit version with 64bit dll(on 64bit Win7/WindowsServer2003). The application start OK. But when I hit start button on the app, where the app create thread and start interacting with the dll, the thread will crash/stop at the first call to dll function. 
Below is the error generated, when I close the app.

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:        APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:          DelayServer.exe
>
> Application Version:       1.0.0.0
>
> Application Timestamp:     52092104
>
> Fault Module Name:         KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:      6.1.7601.17965
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:    506dcae6
>
> Exception Code:            e0434352
>
> Exception Offset:          000000000000bccd
>
> OS Version:                                6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
>
> Locale ID:                                 2057
>
> Additional Information 1:                  7315
>
> Additional Information 2:
>   73159f4fb34892aabcc4ba245f14f64e
>
> Additional Information 3:                  d5ec
>
> Additional Information 4:
>   d5ec134b8e354c23783e48c0e2e572da

I understand that this is possible if there is a mismatch between the EXE and DLL i.e. EXE being a 32bit and DLL being 64bit or vice versa.
Attached is the screenshot of my settings. I didn't find a way to verify/edit my x64 platform settings.

[x64 Project Build Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Qau.jpg)

My Development computer is Win Vista 32bit and I have installed 64bit compilers.

I have 32bit targeted application using 32bit dll working OK on 32bit comupters. 
**The crash happens when I run 64bit targeted application with 64bit dll on 64bit computer**

I tried dependencywalker, but I can't expland further to find any dependencies.

Can someone please help me with this.

Many Thanks
Sam

Comment: So your trying to build an x64 app on a x32 machine?

Comment: Yes. Is that wrong?? I believe I am building for x64 as.I selected this in platform target, but I dont know how to edit/verify the settings for x64 platform.

Comment: You gave us a description of the compile environment, now give us a description of the execution environment.  What version of Windows is that, what versions of .NET are installed?

Comment: Actually, and if you have no unmanaged dependencies - you should try to avoid assigning bitness to managed dlls and exes. The runtime will handle this issue for you.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The execution is on 64bit (Win7/Windows Server 2003). I checked .Net ennvironment is 4.0+. The app starts OK when I open. But when I click a start button on the app, It should make a 64bit dll function calls. The app crash right there.. I can't open the app on 32bit computer as it complain that "version of the file is not compatible with version of windows running"

Comment: @Arielr: I dont have no unmanaged depencies as per my knowledge. Can you please explain your recommendation bit more..

Comment: @SamVen: Are you saying that the 3rd party DLL is pure .NET code?  If it has any machine code at all, it's an "unmanaged dependency", and you should check with [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com) to make sure that all the support DLLs it needs are also present and found properly.

Comment: You should be able to at least get a stack trace of the failure, using Dr. Watson or WinDbg or the Visual Studio Remote Debugger Agent.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally resolved the problem.

When I used Microsoft Debug Diagnostic Tool (from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26798) the crash dump shows that there is a problem loading my external dll or its dependencies. I then loaded the my external dll into Dependency Walker (http://dependencywalker.com/) it shows that it can't find a dependency "msvcp100.dll" which is linked to Microsoft VC++.

So I installed Microsoft re-distributable package (x64) and my app doesn't crash any more.

Thanks every one for your help...

Comment: Please accept your answer as the correct one, so we can easily see the issue has been solved. See [accepting answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). ;)